# Data services - find entity by child value

Tags: wcf, linq, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I'm using WCF Data services with Entity Framework 4.1

I have 2 tables with many to many relationship.
I'm trying to get an entity based on a child value.

```
Table 1 (Suppliers) -> ID (PrimaryKey) ,Name ,isEnabled ,Timestamp
Table 2 (Categories) -> RGID (PrimaryKey) , Name, etc....
```

I've tried to to write the URI like this. 
My goal is to retrieve all Suppliers that has a Category with RGID = 3.

```
http://localhost/WCFS/WCFService.svc/Suppliers?$expand=Categories&$filter=RGID eq 3
```

and like this

```
   http://localhost/WCFS/WCFService.svc/Suppliers?$expand=Categories&$filter=Categories/RGID eq 3
```

no luck.
for the second attampt I get

```
The 'RGID ' is not allowed at position 11. Member access or specifying a type identifier on a resource set reference is not allowed.
```

So how to do it???

thanks

Comment: Are you passing SQL commands through the URL? your RGID eq 3, are you sticking that into a query somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use navigation:

```
~/Categories(3)/Suppliers
```

Comment: Great!!!. How to make it return only some field of the Supplier entity??? Like Name, Timestamp

Comment: Use the $select query option. So for example ~/Categories(3)/Suppliers?$select=Name,Timestamp